# Threejs squares are displayed as rectangles

Tags: javascript, three.js, vue-cli

I am currently doing a vue-cli project with three.js. I created three square surfaces perpendicular to each other, each with a side length of 2. I also uses a `Camera` and `OrbitControl` to view and control the perspective of the camera. However, the result is like this:

[image: Square surfaces changes to rectangular plane in the view]

Two square planes are displayed as rectangular planes instead of square planes in the view.

My vue component code is shown below:

```js
<template>
  <canvas id="canvas" ref="canvas" class="w-100 h-100">

  </canvas>
</template>

<script>
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

export default {
  name: 'Canvas',
  data: function() {
    return {
      strokes: [],
      paint: false,
      scene: {},
      renderer: {},
      camera: {},
      controls: {},
      mouse: {},
      planes: [],
      planeMaterial: {},
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let self = this; // reference to Vue "this"
    let canvas = this.$refs.canvas; // reference of canvas DOM

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.$refs.canvas });
    this.renderer.setSize(canvas.offsetWidth, canvas.offsetHeight);
    
    // setting the camera and orbitControl
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, canvas.offsetWidth / canvas.offsetHeight, 1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 50;
    this.camera.target = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.minDistance = 50;
    this.controls.maxDistance = 200;
    this.controls.mouseButtons = {
      // LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
      MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.PAN,
      RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    }

    // material for plane
    this.planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.1, transparent: true });
    
    // creating the square planes
    // points used for constructing the planes
    let origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    let p1 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0);
    let p2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0);
    let p3 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 2);
    let p4 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 2, 0);
    let p5 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 2);
    let p6 = new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 2);

    // creating the planes
    let planeGeometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    let planeGeometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    let planeGeometry3 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    planeGeometry1.vertices = [];
    planeGeometry2.vertices = [];
    planeGeometry3.vertices = [];
    planeGeometry1.vertices.push(origin, p1, p2, p4);
    planeGeometry2.vertices.push(origin, p1, p3, p6);
    planeGeometry3.vertices.push(origin, p2, p3, p5);
    let plane1 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry1, this.planeMaterial);
    plane1.name = "Front";
    let plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry2, this.planeMaterial);
    plane2.name = "Bottom";
    let plane3 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry3, this.planeMaterial);
    plane3.name = "Left";

    // adding the planes to the scene
    this.scene.add(plane1);
    this.scene.add(plane2);
    this.scene.add(plane3);

    // other code and events

    // animate function for three.js
    let animate = function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);      
      self.renderer.render(self.scene, self.camera);
    }
    animate();
  },
}
</script>
```

Is this a problem with my definition of `Camera` or `OrbitControl`? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you generate your geometry. If you create an instance of `PlaneGeometry` and just replace `vertices`, they probably won't match to the face definitions. You can check them by inspecting `geometry.faces`.

I suggest you don't use `PlaneGeometry` but `BufferGeometry` and define the two faces of your squares implicitly by three consecutive vertices. The resulting geometry is also a so called non-indexed geometry.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const p1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  const p2 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  const p3 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0);
  const p4 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  const positions = [];
    
  positions.push( p1.x, p1.y, p1.z );
  positions.push( p2.x, p2.y, p2.z );
  positions.push( p3.x, p3.y, p3.z );
    
  positions.push( p3.x, p3.y, p3.z );
  positions.push( p4.x, p4.y, p4.z );
  positions.push( p1.x, p1.y, p1.z );

  geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
 }
 canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.1/build/three.js"></script>
```